# How can I save mutilple EditText's in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, edit

I'm making a time-table like app for my personal use. What I want to do is: when I enter the lessons on Mon,Tues,wed,Thurs,Fri I want to save these. I found out how to do it for one `EditText` box, but I have 5 lessons on each day. So at the moment I am using [this example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/)

How can I do it for all 5 lessons ( p.s I'm using a save button to save the lessons.)

```
public class Week1_Mon extends Activity {


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.week1_mon);
        editBox =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.week1_mon1);
        editBox1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.week1_mon2);



    }
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0); 
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        editBox.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
        int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
        if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1) {
            editBox.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        }
    }
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
    editor.putString("text", editBox.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("selection-start", editBox.getSelectionStart());
    editor.putInt("selection-end", editBox.getSelectionEnd());
    editor.commit();
}

private EditText editBox;



protected void onResume1() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0); 
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        editBox1.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
        int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
        if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1) {
            editBox1.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        }
    }
}

protected void onPause1() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
    editor.putString("text", editBox1.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("selection-start", editBox1.getSelectionStart());
    editor.putInt("selection-end", editBox1.getSelectionEnd());
    editor.commit();
}

private EditText editBox1;
```

Comment: What are "edit text"'s?

Comment: It's an android UI element.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void savePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor e = sp.edit();
    e.putString(key, value);
    e.commit();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    savePreferences("Monday", editText1.getText().toString());
    savePreferences("Tuesday", editText2.getText().toString());
    savePreferences("Wednesday", editText3.getText().toString());
    savePreferences("Thursday", editText4.getText().toString());
    savePreferences("Friday", editText5.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: Hello again, am i supposed to add that to what i have already got or should i replace my work with that? Sory but i have only just started coding. Also this m,ight help; i have a separate screen for mon,tues,wed,thurs,fri. On each day there are 5 lessons (5 edit boxes) so that text doesnt look like what i need? Thanks

Comment: @user3195144 Then basically copy the code that you have for monday and put it in different views, changing variable names appropriately.

Comment: Ok i have just changed the orignal post to what i have now. It works for the first edittext box (Lesson1) but doesn't work with edittext box 2 (lesson 2) How can i make it work so that it saves for all lessons? Hope to hear back soon, thanks

Comment: @user3195144 Honestly, you need to do some more learning/research. Check out the google developers site. They have great documentation. No offense, but you can't come to stackoverflow expecting people to do your work for you. If you have a specific question that can be answered without looking through a bunch of code/writing a bunch of code, please come back and ask again.

Comment: Ok I understand where you are coming from. I'll try and research some more and hopefully find out myself. Thanks for your help thou. Could you point me in the direction to look for, is it shared preferences? Thanns

Comment: I have been looking around and trying things out but just can't find how to save multiple edit text boxes. I know how to do 1 edit box like shown in original post but not more than 1. I'd thought it would be as simply as coping the code from edit box1 and replacing it to edit box2 then would work. But it doesn't! I wish I knew more but I'm still an early beginner :( can you lead me in a direction cos I can't find anything. Thanks